# C++ Exceptional handling query

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

Can some one please explain how sequence of exceptional handling is taking place in below code? How did it evaluate to

> "~B() called Handler of function try block of D()Exception in D"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class E {
public:
    const char* error;
    E(const char* arg): error(arg) {}
};

class B {
public:
    B() {};
    ~B(){cout<<"~B() called"<<endl;}
};

class D: public B {
public:
    D();
    ~D() { cout<<"~D() called"<<endl; }
};

D::D() try :B(){
    throw E("Exception in D");
} catch(E&e)
{
    cout<<"Handler of function try block of D()"<<e.error<<endl;
};

int main()
{
    try {
        D val;
    }catch(...) {}
}
```

Comment: Explain what about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you construct an object of a class which derives from another class, the base class's constructor is invoked (explicitly or implicitly) before the derived constructor body. You are throwing an exception in `D`'s constructor body. `B` has already been constructed at this point. When the exception propagates out, `B`'s destructor is called to destroy the partially-constructed object.

The second behavior of note is the rethrown exception. A function try block on a constructor always rethrows the exception. It is not possible to ignore an exception. If it were, your object would be left with `B` having been destroyed already. See [GotW #66](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) for a more in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 0):

B get's created for the Try block in the constructor of D. The throw statement ends the execution of the try block causing B to be removed by the destructor:

```
~B() called
```

There should actually be a newline here (are you not getting that or did you omit it?). Then the thrown object E enters the catch block where it is output to the screen:

```
Handler of function try block of D()Exception in D
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When a constructor throws an uncaught exception, base classes get automatically destructed (since they were successfully constructed before the constructor body is entered).  Thus `~B()` gets called before the exception handler catches the exception.